# How do I get the GCE vm instance id using python?

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I am using python. I have the correct project and vm instance names.  So I can query Google Cloud metrics just fine.  But now I need to query some Agent metrics, but it needs the instance id of my vm instead of the name.  What is the simplest way for me to get the instance id of my vm with a query?

Sorry, I should be more clear.  Here is my sample code:

```
results = client.list_time_series(
            request={
                "name": project_name,
                "filter": filter,
                "interval": interval,
                "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
            }
         )
```

I want to make a query similar to this.  Any simple filter I can use, or something else, that will get me the instance_id of a particular instance name?

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside the gce vm you use the Metadata server

```
import requests
metadata_server = "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/"
metadata_flavor = {'Metadata-Flavor' : 'Google'}
gce_id = requests.get(metadata_server + 'id', headers = metadata_flavor).text
gce_name = requests.get(metadata_server + 'hostname', headers = metadata_flavor).text
gce_machine_type = requests.get(metadata_server + 'machine-type', headers = metadata_flavor).text
```

If you are looking to list gce vms check the example in the GCP documentation for using client libraries: [Listing Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/using-libraries#list-instances)